# Comparing different length VARCHAR2 in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

A new table was added where I work to process payments through a new system. The problem is it contains only some information, so I need to match it up with another table to get full information. 
Basically, the column that could match the transactions together is of type varchar2(20) in the old table, but it's varchar2(80) in the new table.

The new table (let's call it Z) can hold anything from an 11 digit reference to a 30-40 character reference (can be digits/letters/some special characters). What I am trying to achieve is match it to the old table (let's call it X) which only contains 11 digit reference numbers.

So, let's say Z table looks like:

```
TransactionType Reference
Purchase        abcd-efgh-1923-aa22
Refund          12345678910
```

And table X looks like:

```
Purchase Reference
Shoes    12345678910
Jacket   10987654321
```

Realistically, I would want to find for a refund and a given reference, what the purchase was.

I am quite new to SQL and I've been trying to see what cast/convert might do, but I'm a bit lost here as I've tried both cast and convert.

I tried:

```
select purchase from x, z
where x.reference=z.reference;

select purchase from x,z
where to_number(x.reference)=to_number(z.reference);

select purchase from x,z
where x.reference=cast(z.reference as varchar2(20)); --- and viceversa, casting x to varchar2(80)
```

There is no output, although when I check for let's say refunds on a day and then the purchases on the same day, there will be some references that match. So let's say, for a day I would have expected 5 rows being returned, yet no rows are returned.

Comment: If both columns are `varchar2`, why do you need to do any conversion? Your first query ought to be enough. SO, the values probably don't match - can you check if either column has trailing spaces, for example? You might find it useful to `dump()` the values in both columns so see if they differ, as that will make any invisible space/control character more obvious.

Comment: Moreover, if columns' datatype is `CHAR`, its contents is right-padded with spaces so you should use `TRIM` function instead of `TO_something`. If that's not the case, `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` sample data might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TO_CHAR` function should cover you here:

```
SELECT x.Purchase, x.Reference
FROM X x
INNER JOIN Z z
    ON TO_CHAR(x.Reference) = TO_CHAR(z.Reference)
WHERE z.TransactionType = 'Refund';
```

If you want to restrict to a certain reference, then just include that requirement in the `WHERE` clause.

Note that I refactored your joins to use a modern explicit inner join.  This is the preferred way of writing SQL code.

Comment: Thank you, it did work :) Never thought it would be so simple as the previous casts weren't working for whatever reason.... Thank you!

Comment: @pSYoniK . . . This will work assuming that the original string value does not start with `0`.